# How to save text file?

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ionic3

This is my code.
It doesn't work first installed. but it works when i reinstall apk without uninstalling.

```
 import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
```

.....

```
        let filedir = this.file.dataDirectory ;
        this.file.createDir(filedir,'recordvideo',false);
        this.file.writeFile(filedir + 'recordtext' ,'sample.txt',this.content);
```

Please provide me if you have source code or link.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean _doesnt work?_ Are there any console errors?

Comment: It means that file is not created.
it seems that can not access file directory.
I added alert('succ'); after writefilefunc.
But alert not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "recordvideo" directory should be created properly. But the 'sample.txt' will not be created because you need to create the 'recordtext' directory first then you can create file in it.
Following is the code which will work as you expected:

```
 let filedir = this.file.dataDirectory;
    this.file
      .createDir(filedir, "recordvideo", false)
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Directory created:recordvideo");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(
          "Create Directory Error(recordvideo):" + JSON.stringify(error)
        );
      });

    this.file
      .createDir(filedir, "recordtext", false)
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Directory created:recordtext");
        this.file
          .writeFile(filedir + "recordtext", "sample.txt", "Hello there...")
          .then(data => {
            console.log("File created:sample.txt");
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Create File Error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(
          "Create Directory Error(recordtext):" + JSON.stringify(error)
        );
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
It works well.
I have one problem that when i installed apk, first time. 
I can't read the text which i saved.
But When I reinstall apk without uninstalling previous apk, i can read it.
Do you have got any solution about it?

Comment: @fastworker399 You may be trying to read the file before the file get saved successfully. Can you provide the code of reading the file so that I can help you?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032508/how-to-read-text-file
Please check this question. I attached the files too.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnh20dyivzaui1b/FileSaveRead.rar?dl=0
This is the source.
addtextpage:save file to 'recordtext'
textfilepage:read file from 'recordtext'
This code works well on iphone but not work well on android.