# How to read text file?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I tried to read text from local.
This is my code.

```
ReadFiles()
   {

      var filedir = this.file.dataDirectory ;
      this.file.listDir(filedir,'recordtext').then((files)=>
      {      
           var i =0 ;

           for( let myfile of files){

             this.file.readAsText(filedir,myfile.fullPath.substr(1)).then((contents)=>{

                 this.pushArray.push(this.getSubStr(contents));
                 this.txtNames.push(myfile.fullPath.substr(1));                      
             })
           }            
      });

   }
```

This is the url of source
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnh20dyivzaui1b/FileSaveRead.rar?dl=0

I can't read file with this code when I installed apk ,first time.
but i reinstall apk without uninstalling the apk, it can read file.
Please help if you have know reason.
Regards.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error message? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
It seems that file access need some time.
Is there any method to set permission programmatically?

Comment: which permissions are you referring to?

Comment: permission of access file.
When i restart the apk, file read success.
But it is not work first time.
It is very strange....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the index.html
I moved src="build/polyfills.js" up

```
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And the problem is solved.